# Efficient way to calculate the pairwise matrix product between one tensor and all the rolling of another tensor

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, tensor

Suppose we have two tensors:

tensor A whose shape is (d,m,n)

tensor B whose shape is (d,n,l).

If we want to get the pairwise matrix product of the right-most matrix of A and B, I think we can use np.einsum('dmn,...nl->d...ml',A,B) whose size is (d,d,m,l). However, I would like to get the pairwise product of not all the pairs.

Import a parameter k, 1<=k<=d, I want to get the following pairwise matrix product:

from

A(0,...)@B(0,...)

to

A(0,...)@B(k-1,...)
;

from

A(1,...)@B(1,...)

to

A(1,...)@B(k,...)
;

....
;

from

A(d-2,...)@B(d-2,...),

A(d-2,...)@B(d-1,...)

to
A(d-2,...)@B(k-3,...)
;

from

A(d-1,...)@B(d-1,...)

to

A(d-1,...)@B(k-2,...)
.

Note here we we use a rolling way to deal with tensor B. (like numpy.roll).

Finally, we actually get a tensor whose shape is (d,k,m,l).

What's the most efficient way to do this.

I know several ways like:

1. First get np.einsum('dmn,...nl->d...ml',A,B), then use a mask to extract the (d,k) pairs.
2. tile B first, then use einsum in some way.

But I think there exists a better way.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you can do much better than a for loop. Here is, for example, a vectorized version using einsum and stride_tricks compared to a double for loop:

[image]

Code:

```
from simple_benchmark import BenchmarkBuilder, MultiArgument
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided
B = BenchmarkBuilder()

@B.add_function()
def loopy(A,B,k): 
    d,m,n = A.shape                                   
    l = B.shape[-1]                     
    out = np.empty((d,k,m,l),int)                      
    for i in range(d):                         
        for j in range(k):                     
            out[i,j] = A[i]@B[(i+j)%d]                      
    return out                     

@B.add_function()
def vectory(A,B,k):                                            
    d,m,n = A.shape                                            
    l = B.shape[-1]                                            
    BB = np.concatenate([B,B[:k-1]],0)                         
    BB = as_strided(BB,(d,k,n,l),np.repeat(BB.strides,(2,1,1)))
    return np.einsum("ikl,ijln->ijkn",A,BB)                    

@B.add_arguments('d x k x m x n x l')
def argument_provider():
    for exp in range(10):
        d,k,m,n,l = (np.r_[1.6,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5]**exp*(4,2,2,2,2)).astype(int)
        print(d,k,m,n,l)
        A = np.random.randint(0,10,(d,m,n))                            
        B = np.random.randint(0,10,(d,n,l))
        yield k*d*m*n*l,MultiArgument([A,B,k])

r = B.run()
r.plot()

import pylab
pylab.savefig('diagwa.png')
```